# Why I can't return object assign it to variable with function which contains AJAX

Tags: javascript

The title is little bit confusing because I am not sure how to explain it. So there is the code:

```
let label = getLabels(min, max)
console.log(label)
```

and `getLabels`:

```
function getLabels(minId, maxId){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajaxs/get-attribute-value-name',
        data: {
            min: minId,
            max: maxId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            return {
                min: data.min,
                max: data.max
            }
        }
    })
}
```

What I get in the console is `undefined`. What is the proper way to assign obejct to `label` variable? Is it good practice at all? Both `data.min` and `data,max` return what is expected. Thank you!

Comment: success is a callback function not a resolve promise function

Comment: `return` causes its immediately containing function to return -- you are returning the object `{ min: ..., max: ... }` from the `success` function, whenever and however it is called -- that does not mean `$.ajax` has to return that or any other value, the two are completely unrelated in that manner. You need to understand how JavaScript works, basically.

Comment: you can do something like `getLabels(min, max).then(sucessfn)` where you can do your operation of data. Dont forget to return $.ajax from getLabels function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thank you very much, all! Shall I delete the question? Because of the duplication.